# url=/api/v0/probes/readiness status=500 Internal Server Error

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

url=/api/v0/probes/readiness status=500 Internal Server Error

Always get this INFO  in Cassandra logs how to resolve this?

Things I did to resolve it which did not worked out

Scale up and down node

and deleting node so that k8s create itself

Can anyone please help here?

every time we end up deleting cluster and redeploying it.

Comment: More information is needed, but a quick google search shows a similar issue. https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra/issues/1200#issuecomment-974869618 If you're at a similar version.

Comment: @philipenix , checking thanks